# Perlin noise - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, algorithm, noise, perlin-noise

I just started with world generation and I've been looking for tutorials on [perlin noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) everywhere but sadly there are not alot to be found on Google.
The last days I followed a tutorial but I can't get my code to work.

Here is my Java method.

```
private static double[][] createNoise(int xn, int yn, int sps) {
    int m = yn * sps;
    int n = xn * sps;
    double[][] u = new double[yn + 1][];
    double[][] v = new double[yn + 1][];

    double[][] x = new double[m][];
    double[][] y = new double[m][];
    double[][] z = new double[m][];

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        x[i] = new double[n];
        y[i] = new double[n];
        z[i] = new double[n];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < yn + 1; i++) {
        u[i] = new double[xn + 1];
        v[i] = new double[xn + 1];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < xn + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < yn + 1; j++) {
            u[i][j] = nextRandom();
            v[i][j] = nextRandom();
        }
    }
    double hx = xn / (n - 1);
    double hy = yn / (m - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            x[i][j] = hx * j;
            y[i][j] = hy * i;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            int xc = (int)x[i][j];
            int yc = (int)y[i][j];

            if (x[i][j] % 1 == 0 && x[i][j] != 0 ) xc = xc - 1;
            if (y[i][j] % 1 == 0 && y[i][j] != 0 ) yc = yc - 1;

            double xr = x[i][j] - xc;
            double yr = y[i][j] - yc;
            double s11[] = {-xr, -yr};
            double s21[] = {-xr, 1 - yr};
            double s22[] = {1 - xr, 1 - yr};
            double s12[] = {1 - xr, -yr};

            double q11 = s11[0] * u[yc][xc] + s11[1] * v[yc][xc];
            double q21 = s21[0] * u[yc + 1][xc] + s21[1] * v[yc + 1][xc];
            double q22 = s22[0] * u[yc + 1][xc + 1] + s22[1] * v[yc + 1][xc + 1];
            double q12 = s12[0] * u[yc][xc + 1] + s12[1] * v[yc][xc + 1];

            z[i][j] = lerp(x[i][j], y[i][j], xc, xc + 1, yc, yc + 1, q11, q12, q21, q22);
        }
    }

    return z;
}
```

The heightmap that the method returns sadly enough looks like this

[image]

As you can see, the first row/column is working, but after that the algorithm seems to fail.
I made sure that the method

```
nextRandom();
```

returns a float value between -1 & 1.

Thanks alot!

Comment: I don't know anything about perlin noise, but one of your problems is here: hx = xn / (n - 1); it will almost always give you 0, because in java this statement is treated as division of two integers, and result is an integer, and then cast to double

Comment: There we go, thank you sir, you just saved the day!

Comment: Without having the full source code (eg the lerp function) I can't be sure but would I be correct in saying that every time you run this you get different noise (the nextRandom() is a red flag for me). The most useful properties of perlin noise is that it is reproducible; i.e. you can get the particular noise value for an (x,y) at any time; knowing only some seeding information and the (x,y) co-ordinates. This is particularly useful for infinite worlds where creating the entire world in one go is obviously unfeasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user @gawi for pointing this out.

```
hx = xn / (n - 1);
```

will divide 2 integers, and most likely return 0.
You can fix this by casting a double to it:

```
double hx = (double)xn / (n - 1);
```

**Then the map just works!**

Comment: I know, but it tells me I have to wait 2 days -.-

Comment: @gawi You should post it as answer, first ;)

Comment: @joe776 I know, but I wasn't sure if this was a problem: sometimes people do this kind of thing on purpose and I really don't know anything about this perlin noise :D

Comment: @gawi I meant, that he cannot accept it, as you only posted it as a comment ;) Spotting that integer division was nice!

Comment: @joe776 I know, but he can accept his post with the answer :), btw Harm-Jan you should correct also second line ;) (hy = yn / (m - 1);) or if it's irrelevant, then modify your code to make it more efficient